# What is the equivalent window.location.href for vue router

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to redirect to a page in my spa after an action in my small vue app. If I
do this with `window.location.href = "/subpage"` the page refreshes and I lose
cached data from my simple storage management.

**The goal** is to redirect without refreshing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Vue router`](https://router.vuejs.org/), and use the `router-link` component.

```
<router-link to="/subpage">Sub page</router-link>
```

Or dynamically via javascript.

```
this.$router.push('/subpage');
```